# Android studio: Retrofit2 POST request not working

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

So, when i make a post request to my api, it run the onFailure fun. The logcat doesn't give an error. Why is that? Im new to android studio.

Can you help me? Thanks!

**Where i send the POST:** http://localhost:3000/test

**Response (Request sent with postman):**

```
{
    "cso": "kobasz!"
}
```

**Heres my code:**

**Main activity:**

```
package com.alms.chatenium

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.testbtn)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        button.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(APIInterface::class.java)
            val obj = RequestModel("djalms")
            retrofit.requestTest(obj).enqueue(
                object:Callback<Response>{
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<Response>,
                        response: retrofit2.Response<Response>
                    ) {
                        textView.text = response.body()?.cso.toString()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, t: Throwable) {
                        textView.text = "Fail!"
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface:**

```
package com.alms.chatenium

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface APIInterface {
    @POST("test")
    fun requestTest(@Body requestModel: RequestModel): Call<Response>
}
```

**Request model:**

```
package com.alms.chatenium

data class RequestModel(
    val username: String
)
```

**Response model:**

```
package com.alms.chatenium

class Response (
    val cso: String
)
```

**Service builder:**

```
package com.alms.chatenium

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object ServiceBuilder {
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:3000/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}
```

API tested with postman, and verified, that the api (NestJS) working.